# What is the equivalent to the LabVIEW Waveform type in Python

Tags: python, datetime, labview

In LabVIEW, there exists a Waveform datatype, for uniformly spaced data that consists of

- A start timestamp
- The space between samples dt
- An array containing data points

How would something equivalent in python look? Would you just create a list of `datetime` based on start time and dt?

Comment: you mean [this](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P8qkSAC)? potentially a [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) with a datetime index. But it depends on what you want to achieve... you could also use a `dict` (or define a class) that holds a [numpy.ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) (Y), a t0 ([datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)) and a delta_t (float or datetime.timedelta; e.g. seconds).

Comment: interesting about the pandas.Series. But in the Series, I would still have to spell out each datapoint, whereas the waveform uses t0 and dt to define the time array, wouldn't I?
I also thought about creating my own class, but that would be unknown by all functions., so I'd end up converting back and forth a lot.

Comment: "*creating my own class, but that would be unknown by all functions*" - it depends on what functionality you need for your class. I'd imagine that if you inherit from the right class, and define the right methods, you could be fine (but I'm no OOP expert...). Also, I'm not too familiar *why* this datatype is implemented in LV like this (besides the obvious memory efficiency); so in Python, I think you're better off with calculating X once and store it with Y (as index).

Comment: @Pete, create your own class which will be able to return data as pandas.Series type, and take pandas.Series type as input. Anyway you'll end up with converting back and forth - and this is what LabVIEW does in functions which are used for waveform processing. There is often implemented calculation of time array based on t0, dt and actual data point. Just, that data is not stored in memory all the time, but is recreated based on the need.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as was suggested one way of achieving this is to convert the waveform into a time list and a value list. Here's one way of doing that (uses JKI JSON Serializer)

[image]

And in python:

```
def timestamp(waveform):
   import datetime
   from datetime import timedelta
   import json
   obj = json.loads(waveform)
   date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(obj['t0'])
   time_list = [date_time_obj+datetime.timedelta(seconds=obj['dt']*i) for i in 
        range(len(obj['y']))]  # your timestamp list
   obj['y'] # your value list
   return "done"
```

I have tested this with plot.ly and it works as expected.